# R- Dealing with changes in my time series period

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have data, in hourly resolution, which looks like this:

```
Time    traffic
6/7/2005 7:00   56718587433
6/7/2005 8:00   76456162968
6/7/2005 9:00   82534038485
6/7/2005 10:00  88796995092

 ...

7/28/2005 10:00 51528036132
7/28/2005 11:00 69610584123
7/28/2005 12:00 76364975533
7/28/2005 13:00 81281257078
```

The data looks like this:
[image: data]

As one can see, there is an obvious seasonality of 1 day (each cycle), of 1 week (7 cycles) - but in a week there is a patern of [5 days-2 days, 5 days 2 days...].

My question is how can I capture this pattern?

Here is what I've done to capture the daily and the weekly seasonality:

```
library(forecast)
data<-read.csv("internet-traffic-data-in-bits-fr.csv")
model <- msts(data[,2], seasonal.periods=c(24,168))
model.fit <- tbats(model)
plot(forecast(model.fit))
```

And this is what I get when I plot the model:

[image: prediction]

How can I improve it?

Comment: You have not explained what model is plotted. It is not the `model` object in your code, which is simply a multiple-seasonal time series. I suggest you use `tbats` to do the modelling instead of whatever it is you are using.

Comment: Man you are a legend - I find you everywhere. I'm actually now in the middle of your excellent book "forecasting - methods and applications", and the data that is plotted is from your website (`internet traffic data in bits-fr`), I also sent you an E-mail few weeks ago and you forwarded it to Denny Meyer... small world.  Sorry for not mentioning - but I'm actually using `tbats` - I will edit it in the code. My question is though, how can I get a better forecast - because as you can see the forecast is not so great.  Thank you so much!! You taught me so much without even knowing :)